# Some Controllers not going to default Index action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC project. I added a few controllers; over time edited in some code some controllers. Might have done something where I landed up in the following problem and now I do not know how to fix it.

Now http://server/Controller1 correctly executes Index action. But http://server/Controller2 does NOT execute the Index action; instead I get "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory." http://server/Controller2/Index works as expected.

I have gone through similar questions. As you can see Controller1/ routing is happening properly. So it is not IIS config. Controller2 has index() function; it is not route config issue as well; I have not added any specific route for Controller1 or Controller2. The route is basically the default route

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the name of your "Controller2" ? Is it ScriptsController? PropertiesController?

Comment: Hello tmg the Controller2 is called Journals. The answer indicated that I might have Journals folder in my website and that turned out to be the problem. Deleting that folder fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have a folder in your website called Controller2, as the webserver is trying to list its contents

Comment: Correct. And the folder might not be visible in Visual Studio, so you have to check for both a physical folder and an IIS virtual folder. Either way, these physical or virtual folders need to be deleted for IIS to forward the requests to MVC.

Comment: Thank you. I indeed had a Controller2 folder in there. Deleted it and everything worked fine.